# is it compulsory to have default constructor to use uniform initialization in c++

Tags: c++, uniform-initialization

1. In the code give below I got an error message that "**there is no
   default constructor**" .that's why I can't use **uniform
   initializer**.
2. When I made a default constructor then I got an error regarding braces .

Kindly highlight the problem about this program and uniform initiallizer.

I am using VS 2012 and C++

```
class Circle {

    double radius;
  public:

    Circle(double r) { radius = r; }
    double circum() {return 2*radius*3.14159265;}
    Circle () {
    cout<<"ALI \n ";
    }
};

int main () {

  Circle baz {30.0};   // uniform init.

  Circle qux{};
  cout << "foo's circumference: " << baz.circum() << '\n';
  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no default constructor

Comment: I don't understand. You can still use uniform initialization without a default constructor, like you do when creating `baz`. Of course if you don't have a default constructor, `{}` won't work.

Comment: That's fine about baz but I am using Vs 2012 .
According to #sharth we cant use it in VS 2012 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported in the released version of Visual C++ 2012.

There's a preview (CTP) that does have partial support for initializer lists here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515. But this particular code won't work even in that preview because the STL hasn't been updated to use initializer lists.
This will work fine is Visual Studio 2013.
I hope it may help.

Answer (score 4):

- Visual Studio 2012 does not support the uniform initialization syntax.
- Visual Studio 2013 supports this code. You can see that here: [Visual Studio 2013 Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwD0t.png)

Comment: Are you sure about this .
because if they don't allow us to do so then is there a problem with using this format of calling constructor.

Comment: @NoumanMaqsood: The code written is valid C++11 code. The compiler is miscompiling it (because it doesn't fully implement the standard).